# Best List lots of Address BUT SIMPLE as well

Tags: website-design, interface-design, user-experience, usability

I am trying to get a *clean* look yet not give up detail when displaying quite a bit of addresses.

Here is the current method using toggling:

[image]

But from a user looking at this, they can't tell which center or location
they are looking for. Thus it is quite hard to find the place they want.

I am open to any ways to display this info that is straight forward yet not crowded.

Comment: You will have to explain what the user *is* looking for, and why they would be viewing this list. Without that information it's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think displaying more information will make the process any easier. Quite the contrary, you will have an overcrowded screen where locations are still difficult to find.

I would instead consider a more straightforward way of filtering locations. It could be an input field where the user can write a location and it filters the results live... or a map... or **since you have all that empty space on the right you could have the location there** (street name? town? depends):

[image]

I'd definitely NOT show the expander for all the results. I would try to add functionality to facilitate some sort of search.

A user can either look for a location close to their home, in that case they could do a search for postcode (most people know their own postcode). If they are looking for a location on some other area, they can instead input an address, or a neighborhood. Or if this is mobile, you can even pull a GPS location (dreaming here) and show the distance to the nearest centers ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, some good ideas I guess. I will see what I can do with that

Comment: That's a lot more than you had when you came here...

Answer (score 0):

@Yisela has some very good points, but if you have to keep categories, the very least would be to **split them in multiple pages**, so the user first selects the category and than is presented with a list within a particular category.

This way the total number of addresses per page is significantly reduced.